# I am getting invalid number error

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON    
DECLARE
    lv_comp_msr VARCHAR2(20000);
 BEGIN
     WITH msr AS
        (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('02,03,04,09,12', '[^,]+',1,LEVEL) AS msr_id
           FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('02,03,04,09,12', '[^,]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL    ) 
     SELECT listagg (measure_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (    ORDER BY measure_id) AS MEASURE_ID 
     INTO lv_comp_msr
    FROM  
          (SELECT measure_id FROM irp_measures_def   ) 
    WHERE measure_id IN  (SELECT listagg (msr_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY msr_id) msr_id
                          FROM msr   ) 
      --and COMP_MSR_FLAG is null
   ;   
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('lv_comp_msr=' || lv_comp_msr); 
END;
```

Comment: I did not understand your intention. You first converted your string `'02,03,04,09,12'`to rows and then again in the query doing `listagg`. Then why did you converted it into rows at first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listagg()` produces a *string*. In your WHERE clause you compare it with `measure_id`, which I'm going to guess is numeric. You're comparing a number and a string, so Oracle performs an implicit datatype conversion. But of course an aggregated comma-separated string can't be converted to a number, hence the ORA-01722 error.

The error is easily avoided. Your have a WITH clause which produces a table of numbers: why are you applying a `listagg()` in the first place? You can just use the output of the sub-query factoring:

```
 WHERE measure_id IN  (SELECT msr_idFROM msr   )
```